# Как изучать ОО проектирование?

Tags: ооп, архитектура

Здравствуйте участники форума!

Программирую на языке Java примерно полгода(да и в целом, наверное программирую столько же), до этого немного затронул C# ну да не суть.

Начинал изучение с: "Изучаем Java" от O REILLY, затем прочитал "Философию Java" Брюса Эккеля (которая с трудом мне далась). После чего попробовал себя в мобильной разработке, изучая книгу от O`REILLY  "Программирование для Android". Но проблема в том, что литература дает техническое понимание языка, имеется ввиду что такое класс, что такое переменная, коллекции. Данная литература не дает ясного понимания того, как я должен сконструировать свои классы, какой класс содержит такие поля , какой такие, как сделать структуру классов красивой, чтоб вся программа не состояла из одного класса в 3000 сток.

К примеру возьмем декомпозицию игры в шашки. Как сконструировать должным образом данную программу?  В моем понимании там должен быть класс Deck, класс самой шашки с произвольным названием, класс Player. Но как сделать эти классы единым целым? Как наладить отношение между объектами, как инкапсулировать логику, чтобы избавиться от повторяющегося кода.

Сейчас не стоит упоминать паттерны проектирования. Потому что если паттерн есть, это не значит, что мы должны совать его везде где попало. Хотелось бы самому создать должную архитектуру программы.

Так вот хотелось бы узнать, а как вы учились конструировать свою архитектуру программы ?

Comment: Практика. Юнит-тесты. Чтение чужого кода.

Comment: было бы крайне интересно услышать ответ на этот вопрос от более опытных участников. от себя могу сказать следующее: методом проб и ошибок понимаешь как поступать в том или ином случае. так же поддержу @enzo что чтение чужого кода может помочь в понимании как надо писать. осталось мелочь найти чужой код с которого можно брать хорошие практики...

Comment: "Чистый код" читали?

Comment: кстати да *Чистый код* тоже рекомендую. еще возможно стоит посмотреть на *Совершенный код*

Comment: Совершенный код есть возможность прочитать.

Comment: Только практика. Нет никакого теоретического подхода, чтобы сразу все складно получалось. Писать код. Писать тесты. Видеть, что какие-то места получаются неудобными в реализации, а какие-то классы сложно тестировать. Думать, как перераспределить обязанности классов и рефакторить. Сверяться с принципами SOLID (без фанатизма). Повторять. Через некоторое время станет получаться лучше.

Comment: Насчет паттернов - зря. В GoF рассматривается процесс разработки текстового редакторав ООП парадигме. Если более глобально - почитайте Брауде *Технология разработки программного обеспечения*, хотя он ориентирован на командную разработку, процесс утрясания набора классов там показан. Ближе к коду - Kent Beck *Implementation Patterns*.

Comment: Здравствуйте, участник!.. хочу заметить, что у нас не форум, а сайт вопросов и ответов. В отличие от принятых на форумах норм дискуссии в нашем сообществе вторичны, первичны чёткие описания проблем и их решений. Это сродни "темам" на форумах, в которых поддерживается "шапка темы" с "краткой выжимкой полезной информации".

Answer (score 5):

Для начала необходимо определиться с приоритетами (без сортировки. 1 пункт не важнее остальных)

1. Выбрать парадигму/технологию. Много их. На слуху MVP, Reactive, functional style и т.д.
2. Понять, что будет происходить с кодом после выпуска приложения - выпустили и забыли или постоянное развитие.
3. Сколько людей будет задействовано в проекте. Если в одно жало, то это одно, если большая команда - совсем другое.

Потом достать большой блокнот(А4 в самый раз) и нарисовать верхнеуровневую блок-схему своего приложения(lifehack карандаш и ластик рулят). Потом по каждому блоку свою небольшую схемку с подробностями реализации. Потом сжечь к чертям и начать заново. Сменить парадигму/технологию, если надо. Повторить 5 раз.

Comment: "Потом сжечь к чертям и начать заново", или разработка методом экстремального программирования xD

Comment: "UPD Накидывайте в комментарии, что в приоритеты добавить, буду обновлять ответ." - В таких случаях принято делать ответ "общим", чтобы не фармить репутацию за чужой счёт.

Comment: @Kromster и в мыслях не было. :)